# How to set up squirrelmail read from Maildir

Tags: imap, maildir, squirrelmail

I have the problem that my squirrelmail is not reading mails from Maildir. So my Inbox in squirrelmail is always empty. How can I fix it?

This should be the path for Maildir: `/home/someuser/Maildir`. The IMAP server is **UW IMAP Server**.

And here is the squirrelmail config:

```
<?php

/**
 * SquirrelMail Configuration File
 * Created using the configure script, conf.pl
 */

global $version;
$config_version = '1.4.0';
$config_use_color = 1;

$org_name      = "SquirrelMail";
$org_logo      = SM_PATH . 'images/sm_logo.png';
$org_logo_width  = '308';
$org_logo_height = '111';
$org_title     = "SquirrelMail $version";
$signout_page  = '';
$frame_top     = '_top';

$provider_uri     = 'http://squirrelmail.org/';

$provider_name     = 'SquirrelMail';

$motd = "";

$squirrelmail_default_language = 'en_US';
$default_charset       = 'iso-8859-1';
$lossy_encoding        = false;

$domain                 = 'teteet.uni.me';
$imapServerAddress      = 'teteet.uni.me';
$imapPort               = 143;
$useSendmail            = false;
$smtpServerAddress      = 'teteet.uni.me';
$smtpPort               = 25;
$sendmail_path          = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$sendmail_args          = '-i -t';
$pop_before_smtp        = false;
$pop_before_smtp_host   = '';
$imap_server_type       = 'uw';
$invert_time            = false;
$optional_delimiter     = '.';
$encode_header_key      = '';

$default_folder_prefix          = 'INBOX.';
$trash_folder                   = 'Trash';
$sent_folder                    = 'Sent';
$draft_folder                   = 'Drafts';
$default_move_to_trash          = true;
$default_move_to_sent           = true;
$default_save_as_draft          = true;
$show_prefix_option             = true;
$list_special_folders_first     = true;
$use_special_folder_color       = true;
$auto_expunge                   = true;
$default_sub_of_inbox           = true;
$show_contain_subfolders_option = false;
$default_unseen_notify          = 2;
$default_unseen_type            = 1;
$auto_create_special            = true;
$delete_folder                  = true;
$noselect_fix_enable            = false;

$data_dir                 = '/usr/local/squirrelmail/temp/';
$attachment_dir           = '/var/local/squirrelmail/attach/';
$dir_hash_level           = 0;
$default_left_size        = '150';
$force_username_lowercase = false;
$default_use_priority     = true;
$hide_sm_attributions     = false;
$default_use_mdn          = true;
$edit_identity            = true;
$edit_name                = true;
$hide_auth_header         = false;
$allow_thread_sort        = false;
$allow_server_sort        = false;
$allow_charset_search     = true;
$uid_support              = true;


$theme_css = '';
$theme_default = 0;
$theme[0]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/default_theme.php';
$theme[0]['NAME'] = 'Default';
$theme[1]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/plain_blue_theme.php';
$theme[1]['NAME'] = 'Plain Blue';
$theme[2]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/sandstorm_theme.php';
$theme[2]['NAME'] = 'Sand Storm';
$theme[3]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/deepocean_theme.php';
$theme[3]['NAME'] = 'Deep Ocean';
$theme[4]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/slashdot_theme.php';
$theme[4]['NAME'] = 'Slashdot';
$theme[5]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/purple_theme.php';
$theme[5]['NAME'] = 'Purple';
$theme[6]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/forest_theme.php';
$theme[6]['NAME'] = 'Forest';
$theme[7]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/ice_theme.php';
$theme[7]['NAME'] = 'Ice';
$theme[8]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/seaspray_theme.php';
$theme[8]['NAME'] = 'Sea Spray';
$theme[9]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/bluesteel_theme.php';
$theme[9]['NAME'] = 'Blue Steel';
$theme[10]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/dark_grey_theme.php';
$theme[10]['NAME'] = 'Dark Grey';
$theme[11]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/high_contrast_theme.php';
$theme[11]['NAME'] = 'High Contrast';
$theme[12]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/black_bean_burrito_theme.php';
$theme[12]['NAME'] = 'Black Bean Burrito';
$theme[13]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/servery_theme.php';
$theme[13]['NAME'] = 'Servery';
$theme[14]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/maize_theme.php';
$theme[14]['NAME'] = 'Maize';
$theme[15]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/bluesnews_theme.php';
$theme[15]['NAME'] = 'BluesNews';
$theme[16]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/deepocean2_theme.php';
$theme[16]['NAME'] = 'Deep Ocean 2';
$theme[17]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/blue_grey_theme.php';
$theme[17]['NAME'] = 'Blue Grey';
$theme[18]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/dompie_theme.php';
$theme[18]['NAME'] = 'Dompie';
$theme[19]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/methodical_theme.php';
$theme[19]['NAME'] = 'Methodical';
$theme[20]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/greenhouse_effect.php';
$theme[20]['NAME'] = 'Greenhouse Effect (Changes)';
$theme[21]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/in_the_pink.php';
$theme[21]['NAME'] = 'In The Pink (Changes)';
$theme[22]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/kind_of_blue.php';
$theme[22]['NAME'] = 'Kind of Blue (Changes)';
$theme[23]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/monostochastic.php';
$theme[23]['NAME'] = 'Monostochastic (Changes)';
$theme[24]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/shades_of_grey.php';
$theme[24]['NAME'] = 'Shades of Grey (Changes)';
$theme[25]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/spice_of_life.php';
$theme[25]['NAME'] = 'Spice of Life (Changes)';
$theme[26]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/spice_of_life_lite.php';
$theme[26]['NAME'] = 'Spice of Life - Lite (Changes)';
$theme[27]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/spice_of_life_dark.php';
$theme[27]['NAME'] = 'Spice of Life - Dark (Changes)';
$theme[28]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/christmas.php';
$theme[28]['NAME'] = 'Holiday - Christmas';
$theme[29]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/darkness.php';
$theme[29]['NAME'] = 'Darkness (Changes)';
$theme[30]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/random.php';
$theme[30]['NAME'] = 'Random (Changes every login)';
$theme[31]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/midnight.php';
$theme[31]['NAME'] = 'Midnight';
$theme[32]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/alien_glow.php';
$theme[32]['NAME'] = 'Alien Glow';
$theme[33]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/dark_green.php';
$theme[33]['NAME'] = 'Dark Green';
$theme[34]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/penguin.php';
$theme[34]['NAME'] = 'Penguin';
$theme[35]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/minimal_bw.php';
$theme[35]['NAME'] = 'Minimal BW';
$theme[36]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/redmond.php';
$theme[36]['NAME'] = 'Redmond';
$theme[37]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/netstyle_theme.php';
$theme[37]['NAME'] = 'Net Style';
$theme[38]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/silver_steel_theme.php';
$theme[38]['NAME'] = 'Silver Steel';
$theme[39]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/simple_green_theme.php';
$theme[39]['NAME'] = 'Simple Green';
$theme[40]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/wood_theme.php';
$theme[40]['NAME'] = 'Wood';
$theme[41]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/bluesome.php';
$theme[41]['NAME'] = 'Bluesome';
$theme[42]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/simple_green2.php';
$theme[42]['NAME'] = 'Simple Green 2';
$theme[43]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/simple_purple.php';
$theme[43]['NAME'] = 'Simple Purple';
$theme[44]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/autumn.php';
$theme[44]['NAME'] = 'Autumn';
$theme[45]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/autumn2.php';
$theme[45]['NAME'] = 'Autumn 2';
$theme[46]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/blue_on_blue.php';
$theme[46]['NAME'] = 'Blue on Blue';
$theme[47]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/classic_blue.php';
$theme[47]['NAME'] = 'Classic Blue';
$theme[48]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/classic_blue2.php';
$theme[48]['NAME'] = 'Classic Blue 2';
$theme[49]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/powder_blue.php';
$theme[49]['NAME'] = 'Powder Blue';
$theme[50]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/techno_blue.php';
$theme[50]['NAME'] = 'Techno Blue';
$theme[51]['PATH'] = SM_PATH . 'themes/turquoise.php';
$theme[51]['NAME'] = 'Turquoise';

$default_use_javascript_addr_book = false;
$abook_global_file = '';
$abook_global_file_writeable = false;
$abook_global_file_listing = true;
$abook_file_line_length = 2048;

$addrbook_dsn = '';
$addrbook_table = 'address';

$prefs_dsn = '';
$prefs_table = 'userprefs';
$prefs_user_field = 'user';
$prefs_key_field = 'prefkey';
$prefs_val_field = 'prefval';
$addrbook_global_dsn = '';
$addrbook_global_table = 'global_abook';
$addrbook_global_writeable = false;
$addrbook_global_listing = false;

$no_list_for_subscribe = false;
$smtp_auth_mech = 'none';
$imap_auth_mech = 'login';
$smtp_sitewide_user = '';
$smtp_sitewide_pass = '';
$use_imap_tls = false;
$use_smtp_tls = false;
$session_name = 'SQMSESSID';
$only_secure_cookies     = true;
$disable_security_tokens = false;
$check_referrer          = '';

$config_location_base    = '';

@include SM_PATH . 'config/config_local.php';
```

Comment: So, what about that IMAP server your config is pointing towards?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not squirrelmail, but your IMAP-Server. Dovecot only connects to the local IMAP-server (in your config the options `$domain`, `$imapServerAddress` and
`$imapPort` define this connection), which offers to the client the mails he sees.

For dovecot, see the docs on [MailLocation/Maildir](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailLocation/Maildir), for cyrus I could't find a doc for that specific topic, just see your configs there.

Comment: I use UW IMAP server...

Comment: Does the UW IMAP server work with other IMAP clients, like mutt or thunderbird and alike?

Answer (score 0):

Squirrelmail doesn't read from the Maildir directly. It reads from and IMAP server.  It appears you may not be connecting to the IMAP server.  I use Dovecot as an IMAP server.

You can connect to the IMAP server using Telnet and test out connectivity.  Once you have IMAP working, then you can move on to getting Squirrelmail working.  With IMAP you can also use other clients like Thunderbird to connect and read mail.

EDIT: Check your log files.  Dovecot actions should be logging to mail.log and syslog. You may also find information in the apache error.log.  Also check the logs of your IMAP server to see what it reveals.  Try setting the default folder prefix to an empty string (`$default_folder_prefix=''`).

Comment: I use UW IMAP server and it's work fine, problem is I squirrelmail don't read mails...

Comment: @Vladimir See my edit